# Accessing BigQuery via SQL Developer

Tags: google-bigquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to Google's BigQuery (BQ). I am looking for a way to use SQL Developer (SD) as my primary GUI.

I have tried setting up a third party JDBC, but it does not seem to work. I downloaded Google's JDBC drivers for BQ and tried setting it up as a third party connection in SD. It registers, but does not show on the create new connection.

It is supposed to show up as a new Connection Type tab, but nothing is shown.

Is it possible to access BigQuery with SQL Developer? If so, can anyone provide me with the correct steps to duplicate?

Comment: as you are new to BigQuery - why not to start just with what the great stuff BigQuery Team provides you with already!?

Comment: Though I can use the web gui, it is clunky and not the desirable. This is why I am looking to use a third party gui.

Comment: try Goliath. It is available on Google Cloud Marketplace as a part of [Potens.io](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio) . You can check [product videos](https://potensio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us) before jumping in :o)

Comment: Mikhail - While Goliath looks good, I am looking at SQL developer because of its simplicity and cost.  Free is hard to beat.

Comment: P.S. Goliath is **free** for you to use. 14 days free trial is for Magnus only and even those 14 days are flexible depends on your use-cases

Comment: Disclosure: I am an author and leader of team behind the Potens.io as well as author and creator of BQ Mate - you can see more in my profile :o)

Comment: You can use [superQuery Web IDE](https://web.superquery.io/) which is another market place option which provides Full IDE solution as SD does plus cost optimization solution for your queries. You can also use the web MySql Connector see an example [here](https://web.superquery.io/python/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Simba Driver](https://www.simba.com/drivers/bigquery-odbc-jdbc/)? It provides not only JDBC, but ODBC (3.8 is supported) as well.

Alternatively you can check this documentation on how to [Access BigQuery Data as a Remote Oracle Database](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/bigquery-odbc-oracle-hs.rst).